# Regex pattern for adding N before string value in sql statement

Tags: sql, regex, unicode, nvarchar

I need help with the regex pattern to add N before all string values in sql-statements

For example:

**Before:** `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '123';`
**After:** `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = N'123';`

In that example, I can use this pattern: `'[^']+'`.  However, I need help with pattern for this example:

**Before:** `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = 'One''Two' AND column2 = 'abc';`
**After:** `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = N'One''Two' AND column2 = N'abc';`

If there's a double `''`, it should skip those.

**Information about my problem:** [You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114081311/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/239530/en-us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use something like this to satisfy the above (provided whatever you're using to apply it supports a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!')'[\w]+?'
```

It's using a negative lookbehind to exclude captures between `'` and `'` that are preceded by another `'`. You may have to adapt the `\w` if you required spaces/other characters.

**Edit** (Updated answer to include your extra strings from the comments):

You could try:

```
(?<=\s)'.*?'
```

Which will capture zero or more characters occurring between `'` characters (ungreedy), and uses a positive lookbehind to ensure the first `'` is preceded by a space character, which should satisfy all the strings you've listed.

You could optionally add a negative lookahead on the end `(?!\w)` to skip over the `'` in O'Connor.

Comment: Glad it was what you're after =D

Comment: I've found out a problem with the pattern, this example doesn't work:
**select * from table where id = 'This example does not work, O'Connor says'**

I change the pattern to **(?<!')'[^']+?'** and then everything works   except if it is a empty string like **id = ''**

Comment: Hi, I think If you use that approach, you won't be able to match your original examples. I've updated my answer with something that should cover all your cases.

Comment: Hi again, I found out with the last one does not work in **IN('123', '456')** statements. No N will be added at the first value. It seems hard to get all cases to work.

Comment: You could add an `or (` to the negative lookahead, e.g. `(?<=\s|\()'.*?'`